# How is eks cluster accessible when deployed in a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

When deploying an EKS cluster, the best practice is to deploy the managed control plane in private subnets. In terms of accessibility, the defalt option is `public` cluster, meaning that I can access it locally with `kubectl` tool and updated kubeconfig.

How am I able to access the cluster if it is deployed in private subnets with no inbound traffic? As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-endpoint.html), AWS creates a managed endpoint that can access the cluster from within the AWS network.

What is the architecture behind it, how does it internally work? Is there some kind of a proxy (agent) being deployed (found `aws-node`)?

1. deployed my own EKS cluster
2. read the documentation
3. tried to scrape for additional info

Answer (score 1):

The type of EKS networking you're setting up is configured to restrict access to the API server with a private endpoint that's only accessible from within the VPC. So any Kubernetes API requests (kubectl commands) have to originate from within the VPC (public or private subnets). If you are doing this as a personal project, then you can do the following:

1. Create a [bastion host](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/linux-bastion/) in the public subnet of your VPC with a key pair. Launch this host with user data that installs kubectl and any other CLI tools you need.
2. Access the bastion host via SSH from your workstation to ensure it works as expected.
3. Check that the security group attached to your EKS control plane can receive 443 traffic from the public subnet. You can create a rule for this if one doesn't exist. This will enable communication between the bastion host in the public subnet and the cluster in the private subnets.
4. Access the bastion host and then use it to communicate with the cluster just as you would with your personal machine. For example, run `aws eks --region <region> update-kubeconfig --name <name-of-your-cluster>` to update your kubeconfig and then proceed to run kubectl commands.

Sidenote:
If this is for an enterprise project, you can also look into using AWS VPN or DirectConnect to access the VPC.

Other helpful resources:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/de-mystifying-cluster-networking-for-amazon-eks-worker-nodes/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-endpoint.html#private-access

Answer (score 0):

Actually AWS does not deploy the EKS control plane in your subnet. The control plane is deployed to another VPC controlled by AWS which is not visible to the customer. So the type of "cluster endpoint access" (private, public or both) doesn't related to your subnet type(private or public)

So you might ask why you need to select subnets while you creating EKS Cluster. The reason is, EKS attaches network interfaces to your subnets (in your case private) so that EKS control plane(in AWS managed VPC-not visible to you) and your nodes (in your VPC) can communicate. Those network interfaces are used when your cluster endpoint access API is private and your nodes are in private subnet.

For more detailed information you can check following aws blog post about the topic: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/de-mystifying-cluster-networking-for-amazon-eks-worker-nodes/